# Angular @Input pass number value from parent component to child component

Tags: angular

while passing number value from parent to child is coming as undefined but if I pass object its defined.

```
parent.component.ts
    value = 10

    parent.component.html
    <child [value]="value"></child>

    child.component.ts
    @Input() value;

    ngOnInit(){
    this.value/// undefined}
```

Working

```
parent.component.ts
value = {val:10}
```

Comment: Maybe your parent component is updating `value` after the child's `ngOnInit` is run.

Comment: Do you experience the same problem if you create an [mcve] using https://stackblitz.com? If so please save it and share the link. The code above should  run fine so there is something else going on that you are not showing / including.

Comment: Here is a simple working [example](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-3pbpkn)